# Finding phrases in a String

Tags: javascript, search

I've got an array of words that I want to find in a String. I'm doing this in JavaScript,

```js
var lotsOfText = "blahmehfoobar hello random stuff here blahblah blegh coding stackover flow computersc ience";

var textToFind = ["blah", "random stuff", "stackover flow comput"];
var counter = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < textToFind.length; i++) {
  var text = textToFind[i];
  for (var j = 0; j < lotsOfText.length; j++) {
    if (text.charAt(0) === lotsOfText.charAt(j)) {
      if (text === lotsOfText.substring(j, text.length)) {
        counter++;
        j = text.length - 1;
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(counter);
```

Right now, the counter = 1

I don't know where its going wrong.

Also, is there a better/faster way of doing this? Maybe something that doesn't require two for loops and multiple passes through the string text?

Edit: I want to find ALL occurrences of each word in the string. So, as it is now, counter should return 5

Comment: So what should the counter be, 3 ?

Comment: `textToFind.map(word => lotsOfText.includes(word)).reduce((s, i) => s+= i?1:0)`

Comment: indexOf will give you the start index of any combination of letters in a string or -1 if the word doesn't occur in the string.

Comment: `var counter = textToFind.reduce((a,b)=>a+(lotsOfText.includes(b)?1:0),0);`

Comment: Should probably mention that 'includes()' is not supported on IE or early versions of Edge as well as other semi-commonly used browsers. You may need a polyfill or use indexOf() as indicated in some of the answers.

Comment: if `lotsOfText = "foobar bar bar"` and `textToFind = ["foobar", "bar"]` what is the expected result? 4 or 3 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var lotsOfText = "blahmehfoobar hello random stuff here blahblah blegh coding stackover flow computersc ience";

var textToFind = ["blah", "random stuff", "stackover flow comput"];
var counter = 0;

textToFind.forEach(function(frase){
    counter+=(lotsOfText.match(new RegExp(frase, 'g')) || []).length;
});
console.log(counter);
```

Comment: What if there are multiple occurrences of one word in the string? Won't your solution just look at one occurrence and ignore the rest?

Comment: @HumanCyborgRelations probably you should specify better what you need to achieve in your question.

Comment: @HumanCyborgRelations updated, sorry I couldn't read in your question something about more occurrences

Comment: @HumanCyborgRelations you should close the question marking my answer as true if it is correct

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.search()`. I've created a **jsbin** to help you out a bit: http://jsbin.com/seregexuxi/edit?js,console

Basically, it'd look something like this:

```
var lotsOfText = "blahmehfoobar hello random stuff here blahblah blegh coding stackover flow computersc ience";
var textToFind = ["blah", "random stuff", "stackover flow comput"];
var counter = 0;

textToFind.forEach(x => {
  if (lotsOfText.search(x) > -1) {
    counter++;
  }
});
```

Now, this doesn't look for the exact wording, but I'm not sure what you're after. For example, it finds "blah" because of "blahmehfoobar".

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```
var lotsOfText = "blahmehfoobar hello random stuff here blahblah blegh coding stackover flow computersc ience";

var textToFind = ["blah", "random stuff", "stackover flow comput"];
var counter = 0;

var j;

for (var i = 0; i < textToFind.length; i++) {
    j = 0;
    while( true ) {
        j = lotsOfText.indexOf( textToFind[ i ], j );
        if( j !== -1 ){
            counter++; 
            j += textToFind[ i ].length;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically

```
sometext.indexOf( str, start )
```

returns the position (first character is `0`) of the first occurrence of `str` inside `sometext` starting from the position `start`

If `str` is not found then `indexOf` returns `-1`

For each string in the array an occurrence is searched in `lotsOfText`. If an occurrence is found `counter` is incremented and another occurrence of the same string is searched **after** the last occurrence found.

When no (more) occurrences are found the `while` loop is exited and the next string in the array is processed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to check for the existence (and number of occurrences) of each string:

```
var lotsOfText = "blahmehfoobar hello random stuff here blahblah blegh coding stackover flow computersc ience";
var textToFind = ["blah", "random stuff", "stackover flow comput"];
var counter = 0;

textToFind.map(function(word) {
  // create the regular expression ('g' means will find all matches)
  var re = new RegExp(word, 'g');
  // add the number of matches found in lotsOfText
  counter += (lotsOfText.match(re) || []).length || 0;
});

console.log(counter)
```

This code just counts the total number of matches (even if they occur as a substring), but you can see the basic structure and it can easily be manipulated to fit whatever your exact needs are.